# How to put two function calls in a HTML file?

Tags: javascript, html, webpack

I'm learning Solidity (for smart contracts) and now need to design a UI to interact with a deploy contract.

Note: If the question is not relevant to this forum, please kindly let me know (instead of downvoting) and I'll remove it.

---

My HTML and .js files are as below. The problem is that, when I include both "distribute()" and "update_exchange_rate()" functions in .js file, my HTML file would not work. But I wouldn't have any problem if I remove either of them from .js file.

**Question**: Why am I having this problem? How to solve the above problem? Can I have multiple functions (definitions) in window.app?

---

Edit: If I put both functions in .js files, I also get webpack error. But the error will disappear if I remove one of the functions.

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
<script src="./app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>MetaCoin</h1>
<h2>Example Truffle Dapp</h2>
<br>
<br><label for="amountB">Exchange rate:</label><input type="text" 
id="amountA" placeholder="e.g., 95"></input>
<br><label for="receiverA">ReceiverA:</label><input type="text" 
id="receiverA" placeholder="e.g., 95"></input>
<br><label for="receiverB">ReceiverB:</label><input type="text" 
id="receiverB" placeholder="e.g., 95"></input>
<br><br><button id="send1" onclick="App.distribute()">Send 
MetaCoin</button>
<br><br>
<br><label for="amountB">Exchange rate:</label><input type="text" 
id="amountB" placeholder="e.g., 95"></input>
<br><br><button id="send2" 
onclick="App.update_exchange_Rate()">update_exchange_Rate</button>
<br><br>
<br>
</body>
</html>
```

and my js file is:

```
  import "../stylesheets/app.css";
  import { default as Web3} from 'web3';
   import { default as contract } from 'truffle-contract'
  import metacoin_artifacts from '../../build/contracts/MetaCo.json'

  var MetaCo = contract(metacoin_artifacts);
  var accounts;
  var account;
  window.App = {
  start: function() {
  MetaCo.setProvider(web3.currentProvider);
  web3.eth.getAccounts(function(err, accs) {
  if (err != null) {
    alert("There was an error fetching your accounts.");
    return;
  }

  if (accs.length == 0) {
    alert("Couldn't get any accounts! Make sure your Ethereum client is 
    configured correctly.");
    return;
  }
  accounts = accs;
  account = accounts[0];
 });
},
setStatus: function(message) {
var status = document.getElementById("status");
status.innerHTML = message;
},


distribute: function() { // XXX Here is where the problem occures!
var amountA = parseInt(document.getElementById("amountA").value);
var receiver1= document.getElementById("receiverA").value;
var receiver2 = document.getElementById("receiverB").value;
var meta;
MetaCo.deployed().then(function(instance2) {
  meta = instance2;
return meta.distribute(receiver1,receiver2, amountA,{from: account});
})
}

 update_exchange_Rate: function() { // XXX Here is where the problem occures!
  var amountB = parseInt(document.getElementById("amountB").value);
 var meta1;
 MetaCo.deployed().then(function(instance3) {
  meta1 = instance3;
return meta1.update_exchange_Rate(amountB,{from: account});
})
 }
};

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
console.warn("Using web3 detected from external source. If you find 
that your accounts don't appear or you have 0 MetaCoin, ensure you've 
configured that source properly. If using MetaMask, see the following 
link. 
Feel free to delete this warning. :) 
http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/truffle-and-metamask")
// Use Mist/MetaMask's provider
 window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
 } else {
console.warn("No web3 detected. Falling back to http://localhost:8545. 
You should remove this fallback when you deploy live, as it's 
inherently 
insecure. Consider switching to Metamask for development. More info 
here: 
http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/truffle-and-metamask");
// fallback - use your fallback strategy (local node / hosted node + 
in-dapp id mgmt / fail)
window.web3 = new Web3(new 
Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
  }

App.start();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take only this button, the other has the exact same problem...

```
<button id="send2" onclick="App.update_exchange_Rate()">update_exchange_Rate</button>
```

The onclick attribute expects to receive a Function. That function is then called on every click. But the function does not return a function itself...

App.update_exchange_Rate() will get executed as soon as that part is seen by the browser, and it's return value used. But that's not what we want! We want that function to be executed... So we'd need to give the function, and not the call to the attribute, like so:

```
<button id="send2" onclick="App.update_exchange_Rate">update_exchange_Rate</button>
```

or

```
<button id="send2" onclick="function(){App.update_exchange_Rate();}">update_exchange_Rate</button>
```

Now, if you do that you'll certainly end up in a scope you are not expecting. You aren't using `this` in the function so I'll skip that scoping part, you can read about it later if need be.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I tried your suggestion, but it will not run if I remove "()" from App.update_exchange_Rate() or App.distribute().

Comment: I added another possibility. The object and function had to be declared when the HTML got drawn, which might not be the case. Using an anonymous function will circumvent this.

Comment: thanks, I tried that too.  Could you please have a look at the "edit" section that I just added.

Comment: You are missing a colon between the 2 function definitions, that's certainly the error webpack gives you.

Comment: Yes, it's sorted. Thank you for the comments and answer.